# how to use python's yield statement

Tags: python, generator, yield, subset

I have a list of items and would like to generate all possible subsets. Therefore I'm using a recursive function with the item number and a list of all selected items as parameters. The function is called with 0 as the first parameter and does the following:

- It looks at the item described by the index parameter
- It selects it
- It calls itself with an incremented index parameter
- It deselects the item
- It calls itself with an incremented index parameter

I'm needing the possible subsets to optimise something but since the list will get very long, I can't look at all of them. At first I tried to use brute force to take all subsets into consideration but that was a naive idea. Now the new plan is to create a greedy algorithm that takes the first "useful" selection: I want to look at all subsets until I find one that suits my needs and figured that python's yield statement is exactly the right choice. Here's some code:

```
def bruteForceLeft(selected,index):
    #left is the list of which i need subsets
    #its a gobal variable. to test the code, just make sure that you have a 
    #list called left in scope
    if index==len(left):
        #print(selected)
        yield selected
    else:
        #the algorithm stores the selection in a tuple of two lists
        #that's necessary since there's a second list called right as well
        #I think you can just ignore this. Think of selected as a list that
        #contains the current selection, not a tuple that contains the current
        #selection on the right as well as the left side.
        selected[0].append(left[index])
        bruteForceLeft(selected,index+1)
        selected[0].pop()
        bruteForceLeft(selected,index+1)

#as you can see I pass a tuple of two empty lists to the function.
#only the first one is used in this piece of code
for option in bruteForceLeft( ([],[]) ,0):
    print(option)
    #check if the option is "good"
    #break
```

The output is: nothing

At first I thought that I had made an error in generating the subsets, but in the if condition you can see that I have a commented print statement. If I uncomment this print statement and instead comment out the yield statement all the possible choices are printed - and the for loop is broken

With the yield statement the code runs without error, but it doesn't do anything either.

Comment: I still don't understand what the input/output of this should be.

Comment: This doesn't reply to your question, but unless you're doing this as an exercise, it's probably worth to check [itertools.combinations](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations). All subsets would be the union of the combinations of length(1) to length(n), I believe

Comment: goncalopp, you just reminded me why i love python

Comment: @lhk [we all do](http://xkcd.com/353/) :)

Comment: only the single most popular python question ever!? [The Python yield keyword explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that when you recursively call `bruteForceLeft`, the yielded values don't magically get yielded from the enclosing function. So, you need to re-yield them yourself:

```
def bruteForceLeft(selected,index):
    #left is the list of which i need subsets
    if index==len(left):
        #print(selected)
        yield selected
    else:
        #the algorithm stores the selection in a tuple of two lists
        #that's necessary since there's a second list called right as well
        #I think you can just ignore this. Think of selected as a list that
        #contains the current selection, not a tuple that contains the current
        #selection on the right as well as the left side.
        selected[0].append(left[index])
        for s in bruteForceLeft(selected,index+1):
            yield s
        selected[0].pop()
        for s in bruteForceLeft(selected,index+1):
            yield s
```

(Edit: I actually just tested this, and your code has errors, but I'm pretty sure not re-yielding is the problem)

Comment: hm, i can accept an answer in 6 minutes - i guess we have to wait

Comment: Okay. Do you perchance have a global variable `left` or something? I'm really confused how this code works. (it's throwing errors when I run it)

Comment: yep. left is a global variable. I thought the comments had documented this, but you're right. they only say that left is a list. i'll edit that